# Ubuntu MATE is getting the wrong IP address

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, dhcp, mate

I have a job online and my ISP runs an ethernet cable directly into my house (Internet over Power). My Job has a "secure desktop" which is basically a VPNd linux distro running Docky on a flash drive. This "secure desktop" is able to obtain an IP address from the ethernet cord. Ubuntu MATE however isn't. The IP I receive is in the wrong IP range. It starts with 10.x.x.x instead of the public IP my ISP assigns. Interestingly enough, when I plug my computer into a router (from Ethernet) the same thing happens. However, when I connect to the same router wirelessly, I get the correct IP address.

When using an ethernet connection, I am unable to access the Internet or any other network services.

Answer (score 1):

Go into network manager and edit your wired connection. Go to the IPv4 tab and set the networking to automatic (dchp).

Comment: This fixed my problem, but now it tries to default to ethernet for internet connection.  Is there a way to default to wi-fi if you have both connected?